# Is partial class specialization just a different way of writing a full specialization?

Tags: c++, templates

Are these two specializations doing essentially the same thing?

```
//generic:
template<class T>
struct A{
  ...
 }

template<class T>
struct A<int>{
  ...
 }

template<>
struct A<int>{
  ...
 }
```

That is, it would seem to me that any partial specialization could be rewritten as a full specialization.

Comment: I'd expect the compiler to issue an error message on the second definition (because `T` isn't used).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not.  Well, in the Turing tar pit, every sufficiently powerful programming technique is equivalent to every other.

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct foo:std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct foo<T,T>:std::true_type {};
```

here, my partial specialization maps two arguments to one.  More advance things, like:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo<T,std::vector<T>>:std::integral_constant<int, 7> {};
```

are also possible.

You can even do this with a single argument `template`:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_func_signature : std::false_type {};

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct is_func_signature< R(Args...) >: std::true_type {};
```

where we pattern match one argument on many type arguments, and extract them.

Partial specialization is a game of pattern matching on arguments that would be valid to the first interface.

Comment: I assume that each partialized template is itself its own class with no internal relationship to the members of the initial generic class, right?

Comment: @Fellowshee: Yes, each specialization is an entirely separate class. The only relationship between them is that the same name can select any of the specializations (depending on the parameters).